# How does a browser recognize "<!DOCTYPE>"

Tags: browser, theory, doctype

What "language" does a browser use in order to recognize !DOCTYPE html in the first place? I hope that makes sense, I have been looking for a good guide to understand how a browser really works but have not yet found one. If anyone has any recommendations it would be super appreciated!! Thank you!

Comment: The doctype tag originated in SGML, I believe - HTML's ancestor.

Comment: There's really only one source worth reading on this, and that's [the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#parsing).